# What exactly is a Tannakian subcategory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, abelian-categories, tannakian-category

I've searched all the standard references (Deligne--Milne, Saavedra-Rivano) and cannot find a definition of *Tannakian subcategory*. What I find is many authors who discuss the Tannakian subcategory generated by an object, which should correspond by Tannaka duality to the image of the Tannakian fundamental group in the automorphisms of the fiber functor applied to that object. Even Deligne--Milne mention this on p.61 without defining the notion. They do define a tensor

Question: What is the definition of a Tannakian subcategory of a Tannakian category?

More specifically: Is a Tannakian subcategory necessarily full?

(*) I would assume it is at least an abelian subcategory closed under tensor products and duals, and containing the unit object. Note the former means that a sequence is exact in the subcategory iff it is in the larger category.

But that leaves open the following possibilities:

1. Let $G$ be a pro-algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$ and $G \twoheadrightarrow H$ a quotient. Then $\mathrm{Rep}_{\mathbb{C}}(H) \subseteq \mathrm{Rep}_{\mathbb{C}}(G)$ is a (full) Tannakian subcategory by any definition.
2. Let $\mathcal{C}'$ the category of $\mathbb{C}$-representations of $C_2$ (let's say a skeletal version), and let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the category whose objects are those of $\mathcal{C}'$ and whose morphisms are all maps of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces. Then $\mathcal{C}'$ is a non-full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ that satisfies (*), and $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to the category of representations of the trivial group. But surely this is not what people mean, right? (In particular, this example is especially evil; the embedding depends on the isomorphism class of the category $\mathcal{C}$.)
3. Now let $\mathcal{C}'$ be the category of $\mathbb{C}$-linear representations of $S_3$, and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category whose objects are those of $\mathcal{C}$ and whose morphisms are those that are $C_2=\{\mathrm{id},(12)\}$-equivariant. Then (assuming we don't do anything too evil), we can view $\mathcal{C}'\subseteq \mathcal{C}$ as an inclusion of subcategories. This inclusion satisfies (*) but it is not full: for example, there is an inclusion from either the trivial representation or the sign representation into the two-dimensional irreducible representation of $S_3$. Somehow, this example seems more allowable than 2., because the inclusion $C_2 \to S_3$ is an epimorphism in the category of (algebraic) groups.

Notice that in all cases, the inclusion functor is a morphism of Tannakian category (it's an exact tensor functor). But it's not clear that it should be called a Tannakian subcategory.

Comment: A tensorial category over $k$ is a rigid abelian tensor category such that $k=\text{End}(1)$, so a tensorial subcategory is a strictly full abelian subcategory closed under tensor products and duals. It is again a tensorial category over $k$. Similarly for tannakian.

Comment: @anon: Do you have a source?

Comment: Reading between the lines in Deligne--Milne and Deligne 1990.

Comment: in [[math/0508479] Quotients of Tannakian Categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508479) J.Milne uses @anon's definition

Comment: almost the same definition (without `strictly') in [[2205.13073] Malcev Completions, Hodge Theory, and Motives](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.13073)